# Not able to open Crystal Reports file (.rpt) in design view

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

When I go to open a .rpt file in either Visual Studio 2010 or 2012. I don't get the report file layout design which I expect. I instead see either blank page or, in the case of VS2012, byte representation of the data in the file. 
Any idea how I can correct this problem in Visual studio? I have SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET FrameWork 4 **(64-bit)** and SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010. I do find it curious that the Runtime Engine specifies 64-bit when the msi I installed was named **CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_7.msi** Anywho, I would appreciate any help to get this working again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports is a 32 bit application. Run the exe installer instead of the msi. The exe actually integrates the runtime, the msi is only for distribution. Here is a [link](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074) to the developer version. The exe is the first download link in the list.

Answer (score 0):

According to information from: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Note 1: To integrate "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio" you must run the Install Executable. Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS.MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only. 
By default Windows 10 does not install the 3.5 framework, CR for VS still needs it. Select it by "Turn Windows feature on or off" and choose both options.

Note 2: SAP Crystal Reports, Developer Version for Visual Studio .NET does NOT 
support Express Editions of any version of Visual Studio .NET.